# How to write changes to the structure Singly linked list?

Tags: c

I need to create a program in which a simply Singly linked list of students will be created. And I need to make it possible to change the name of a given student.
As a result, changes to the structure are not recorded. I don't get an output about a successful recording.
What's my mistake and how to fix?
main.c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define MAX 10
#define KOL 15

struct Student
{
    int id;
    char Name[KOL];
    int Age;
    float AverageRaiting;
    struct Student* nextStudent;
};

void InitStudentList(struct Student** student)
{
    *student = (struct Student*)
        malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    (*student)->id = 1;
    printf("Enter 1 student name: ");
    scanf("%s", (*student)->Name);
    printf("Enter 1 student age: ");
    scanf("%d", &(*student)->Age);
    printf("Enter 1 student average raiting: ");
    scanf("%f", &(*student)->AverageRaiting);
    printf("\n");
    (*student)->nextStudent = NULL;
    struct Student* endStudent = *student;
    for (int i = 2; i <= MAX; i++)
    {
        endStudent->nextStudent =
            (struct Student*) malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
        endStudent = endStudent->nextStudent;
        endStudent->id = i;
        printf("Enter %d student name: ", i);
        scanf("%s", endStudent->Name);
        printf("Enter %d student age: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &endStudent->Age);
        printf("Enter %d average raiting: ", i);
        scanf("%f", &endStudent->AverageRaiting);
        printf("\n");
        endStudent->nextStudent = NULL;
    }
}

void PrintList(struct Student* student)
{
    struct Student* printStudent = student;
    printf("==========================\n");
    printf("Номер         Ім’я         Вік  Рейтинг \n");
    printf("==========================\n");
    while (printStudent)
    {
        printf("%d", printStudent->id);
        printf("%-15s", printStudent->Name);
        printf("%4d", printStudent->Age);
        printf("%8.2f", printStudent->AverageRaiting);
        printf("\n");
        printStudent = printStudent->nextStudent;
    }
    printf("==========================\n");
}

void FreeList(struct Student** student)
{
    if (*student == NULL)
        return;
    struct Student* tmp = *student;
    struct Student* curr_stud;
    while (tmp)
    {
        curr_stud = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->nextStudent;
        free(curr_stud);
    }
    *student = NULL;
}

void ChangeStudentName(int n, char name[KOL], struct Student* students)
{
    struct Student* st = 0;
    for (st = students; st < students + MAX; st++)
    {
        if (st->id == n)
        {
            const int size=sizeof(st->Name);
            if(size && size>=sizeof(name))
            {
                memcpy(st->Name,name,size);
                st->Name[size-1]='\0';
            }
            printf("Changes are recorded");
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int command;
    struct Student* BaseStudent = NULL;
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    InitStudentList(&BaseStudent);
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Enter command:\n 1 - Show students list,\n 2 - Change student name,\n 3 - Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &command);
        switch (command)
        {
        case 1:
            PrintList(BaseStudent);
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            int n;
            char name[KOL];
            printf("Enter student number: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            printf("Enter new student name: ");
            scanf("%s", &name);
            ChangeStudentName(n, name, BaseStudent);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
            FreeList(&BaseStudent);
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error...");
            FreeList(&BaseStudent);
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried recording like this:

```
strcpy(st->Name, name);
```

But it doesn't work too...

Comment: `; st++)` This is not how linked lists work. Did you mean `st = st->nextStudent)` instead? This leads to UB due to accessing invalid memory addresses.

Comment: I'm blind and the debugger is not completely accessible to me.
I understand that a block of code with for doesn't execute correctly. But I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing linked lists and arrays.

The struct you define and the function to initialize the students, show that you are really using a list.
Entries in the list are connected via a pointer. You cannot reach the next entry in the list by applying pointer arithmetics which is basically same as indexing an array.

Lets have a look at your function:

```
void ChangeStudentName(int n, char name[KOL], struct Student* students)
{
    struct Student* st = 0;
    for (st = students; st < students + MAX; st++)
```

You need to advance to next element via link, not via pointer increment. That would only work for arrays.
You also need to detect if you reach the end by checking for a `NULL` pointer instead of a size.

```
    {
        if (st->id == n)
        {
            const int size=sizeof(st->Name);
            if(size && size>=sizeof(name))
```

Here `size` must be same as `KOL` because `Name` is an array (with fixed size) inside the struct. No need to check that.

Also `sizeof(Name)` is only the size of a pointer. Arrays are only passed as a pointer to functions. You cannot get the size of the array inside the function.

You also don't need to compare this at all. It is sufficient that the actual string is not too long for the destination. You can use `strncpy` to verify that. (Don't forget to terminate the string afterwards.)

```
            {
                memcpy(st->Name,name,size);
                st->Name[size-1]='\0';
            }
            printf("Changes are recorded");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

An updated version would look like this:

```
void ChangeStudentName(int n, char name[KOL], struct Student* students)
{
    struct Student* st = 0;
    for (st = students; st != NULL; st=st->nextStudent)
    {
        if (st->id == n)
        {
            strncpy(st->Name, name, sizeof(st->Name));
            st->Name[sizeof(st->Name)-1]='\0';

            printf("Changes are recorded");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```